# Dereference the first part of the pair object for an unordered map

Tags: c++, unordered-map, std-pair

I have a C++ 03 compliant compiler. I am using a pair object when inserting the element into an unordered map using the following code:

```
unordered_map<char, string> mymap;
pair<unordered_map<char, string>::iterator,bool> ret;
ret = mymap.insert(make_pair('A',"A string of some sort."));
    if (ret.second==false)
        cout << "Could not insert an element into an unordered map.\n";
    else
        cout << // how to print the ret.first value here
```

I am having trouble accessing the value pointed to by `ret.first`. How to print out , dereference iterator that is `ret.first`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
cout << (ret.first)->first;
```

Output

```
A
```

[Working demo](http://cpp.sh/6xlo)

When you say `ret.first` you are accessing the iterator from the returned `std::pair<std::unordered_map<char, std::string>::iterator, bool>`.

Once you have the iterator, the next `->first` gets at the `char`, which serves as the key. Similarly `->second` would get at the `std::string` value for that key.